# Form POST method on html page

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, google-app-engine

I am trying to use Form post method or ajax post method in a html page on google app engine but nothing seems to happen.

```
class Email(webapp2.RequestHandler):   
    def post(self):
        '''
        Post method to handle Email requests.
        '''
        print self.request
        self.response.write(self.request)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),("/email",Email)],
                              debug=True)

<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/email" >
<p>
    <label for="byour_name">Your name</label><input type="text" name="byour_name" value="" id="byour_name">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="byour_email_address">Your email address</label><input type="text" name="byour_email_address" value="" id="byour_email_address">
</p>
<p>
    What's on your mind?<br>
    <textarea name="Message" rows="10" cols="25">
    </textarea>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send it!">
</p>
```

Can some help with this i also tried wireshark to check network activity but nothing is happening..

Comment: But if i declare for inside my app.py file then it is working is. But if i try to post from a form declared inside my index.html it does not work

Comment: Have you tried with a relative path instead of an absolute?

Comment: Both but nothing happening...

Comment: I don't think wireshark can show localhost traffic, only traffic on real network interfaces.

Comment: I tried rest client to make same post request. Then it is working properly ....

Comment: Yes you can see localhost traffic if you use loopback interface..

Comment: What do you mean "if i try to post from a form declared inside my index.html"?

Comment: Mean if i return form using app.py it is working but when i am declaring the form in my index.html it is not. Why is that can you help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. I for got to remove below mentioned lines which i used earlier

```
$("form").bind("submit",function(event){
                                    event.preventDefault();
```

As soon as i removed it. It worked..